# validate array of checkbox using getElementById

Tags: javascript, arrays, validation, checkbox

I've got a bunch of checkboxes defined as an array:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="1" id="courseinfo[]">Content
<input type="checkbox" value="2" id="courseinfo[]">Reputation
<input type="checkbox" value="3" id="courseinfo[]">Duration
<input type="checkbox" value="4" id="courseinfo[]">Career
<input type="checkbox" value="5" id="courseinfo[]">Recommended
<input type="checkbox" value="6" id="courseinfo[]">Interests
<input type="checkbox" value="7" id="courseinfo[]">Other
```

I am trying to see if the last one (value=7) is checked, I tried:

```
q2 = document.getElementById("courseinfo[6]").value;
```

That doesn't seem to work.

How can I access the 7th one in the array and then check if its been checked?

I want to use pure javascript.

Comment: Take out the quotes: `q2 = document.getElementById(facilities[6]).value;`

Comment: `"facilities[6]"` ?? doesn't seems id

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan sorry you're right I wrote it incorrectly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have id attribute in your checkbox collection. I think you're meaning `name` attribute. Use `getElementsByName` to get elements to NodeList. Then get 6th element's value.

```
q2 = document.getElementsByName("facilities")[6].value;
```

Use this to check if checkbox is checked:

```
if(q2.checked) {
   alert('You have checked the 6th checkbox!');
}
```

Comment: Right brilliant I missed that part I do have it, how do I acces it to check if its been checked, I have this after: if (q2.checked) {do something}

Comment: I think you mean "courseinfo[]" and not "facilities", but yes, this is right.

Comment: @abu i added example to check if checkbox is checked.

Comment: @josh yes thanks for pointing that out, funny what a cold can do to concentration

Comment: @abu I made some modifications to your jsfiddle, can you try now: http://jsfiddle.net/6GsX3/4/

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementById` is used to get elements from their attribute `id=""`.
What you need here is `getElementsByTagName`

```
var elems = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
if (elems[elems .length-1].checked) {
    // do stuff
}
```